# Target section with angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to target a `section` element with a click event by using this code:

```
removeOfflineNotification(event: any) 
{
   console.log('event clicked', event);
   this.render.addClass(event.target, 'offline-notifier-closed');
}
```

The code works but only on the target that I click on, the html is:

```
<section class="offline-notifier" *ngIf="!isOnline" 
 (click)="removeOfflineNotification($event)">
     <h4>You are currently offline</h4>
     <p>The App will have limited functionality</p>
     <span class="btn btn-primary">Close</span>
</section>
```

if I click on the `span` how can i make the whole section `close` as at the minute the span tag disappears(which is the target) then I have to click again for the section to disappear.

How can I make the section disappear when I click the `span`

Comment: That doesn't look very Angular ... why not `ng-click=` and `$scope.removeOfflineNotification = function` ? (and it's probably a good idea to avoid `this`)

Comment: @Mawg Post is in Angular 4 actually.

Comment: It is Angular 4

Comment: D'oh !  I think we need more [tag:Angular_X] tags

Comment: I have found the way  this.render.addClass(event.currentTarget, 'offline-notifier-closed');